# Why am i getting the "NullPointerException" , when trying to use regex?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I'am getting a

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

when trying to use regex in the following code:

```
public static void scanSTAFFELNR() {

    String STAFFELNR = CsvScanner.values.get(1);  // My values are stored in a ArrayList ( values). Here i want to get the second one.

    if (STAFFELNR.matches("[0-9]+")) { // Here i want to check, if the String is a number. 
        System.out.println("erfolg");
    } else {
        STAFFELNRMessage = "Fehler bei STAFFELNR, STAFFELNR muss zwischen 0-3 sein";
        Gui.fehlerCounter++;
    }
}
```

When i remove the `STAFFELNR.matches`
and replace it with a `STAFFELNR == "Hello"`
, i get no error.

I dont know how to fix this error on my code.

Comment: Then presumably your `STAFFELNR` is `null`. Also don't ever compare strings with `==`. You use `equals()` for object comparisons.

Comment: i dont get why it is null. As soon as i created the String, i gave it a value.

Comment: A `null` value based on the behaviour of your code. Did you put nulls in your arraylist?

Comment: My ArrayList was created in a different Class and filled, when a button was pressed.

Comment: That's probably the root of your problem. `CsvScanner.values.get(1);` returns `null`, so you're not putting things in the `ArrayList` correctly. You are putting nulls in there, because otherwise you'd get a different exception.

Comment: But when i system.print.out(values.get(1)) i get the number i want..

Comment: What about when you do `System.out.println(STAFFELNR);`?

Comment: Nevermind. i got it working..than you=)